# Unusual behavior of API calls on Django + angularjs

Tags: jquery, django, api, angularjs

We have one website which uses Django + Angularjs + jQuery.

Now when we worked on local server, that was working perfectly.

Now as we have moved the data to server, some API calls sends

```
ViewDoesNotExist
```

yellow color page error, instead which has to send JSON object.

But in same api call you call again or refresh the page couple of time, it sends correct JSON reply.

and in a page where we have to call 4-6 API calls one after another, that time browser console will show

```
500 internal server error
```

I have tried to search for particular but it doesn't help.

All the api call which will send json data will be shown in ng-view (where this problem comes).

**What are the things, which i should lookup in setting of django or AngularJs get/post method , to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your production server config is totally broken. First thing to do: check your django settings to make sure you have `DEBUG=False`, `ADMINS` properly configured with your email adresses (so you can get email notifications on unhandled exceptions), and your logging is properly configured (cf django's doc). Then restart your front server (Apache or whatever), so you don't have any stray process running with some old version of your codebase.